# In emacs Python mode, how do I set a different auto-fill width for docstrings and code?

Tags: python, emacs, docstring, pep8, autoformatting

I would like to have auto-fill set to 79 columns for code sections and 72 for docstrings to get automatic PEP8 compliance. There seems to be an option to do this for Lisp mode (emacs-lisp-docstring-fill-column) but not for Python.

Is there an enhanced python-mode.el around somewhere that includes this?

Comment: filed a feature request at https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1028055

Comment: Thanks for taking action on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current python-mode.el provides

```
(defcustom py-docstring-fill-column 72 [...]

(defcustom py-comment-fill-column 79 [...]
```

while for code value of `fill-column` is used.

Comment: @Drew Indeed posted the beginning of the definitions only, hoping it conveys all info needed. Added some ellipsis to make that clear.

Comment: @Drew Hmm, don't understand your concern. Said: python-mode.el provides, i.e. it's a copy from there. The question was about compliance.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you were telling the OP to put those `defcustom`s in his init file.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler, sorry for the noob request, but please could you expand this answer a bit to show how an Emacs user can take advantage of those lines you have quoted from python-mode.el? Thanks!

Comment: @sampablokuper With a defcustom macro, M-x customize-variable RET.. will allow user-defined values. HTH

Comment: @AndreasRöhler, thanks for your reply, and apologies: I should have been clearer about what I was asking. Suppose I'm in Python mode, and am editing a Python file. How can I ensure that when I perform Edit > Fill (or in Evil, `gq`), the wrapping is performed based on the py-docstring-fill-column value if my selected text is in a docstring, or likewise on the py-comment-fill-column value if my selected text is instead in a comment?

Comment: @sampablokuper M-x fill-paragraph RET should DTRT

Comment: @AndreasRöhler, I was using Emacs 24's built-in Python mode, which I have now learned is *not* `python-mode.el` but rather `python.el`. So, I probably need to go and investigate whether I can get `python-mode.el` working for me. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to do that, but I've never felt the need.  It is so easy to use <kbd>C-x f</kbd> to change the fill column.  And you can just hit <kbd>M-p</kbd> to reuse the last value you entered.  Just <kbd>C-x f M-p</kbd> --- 3 keystrokes.

Answer (score 3):

Only slightly tested:

```
(defadvice current-fill-column (around handle-docstring activate)
  (flet ((docp (p) (let ((q (get-text-property p 'face))
                         (r 'font-lock-string-face))
                     (or (eq r q) (memq r q)))))
    (if (or (docp (point)) (docp (point-at-bol)) (docp (point-at-eol)))
        (setq ad-return-value 72)
      ad-do-it)))
```

This depends on *font-lock-mode* being enabled to detect the docstrings.

Comment: Would I tuck this into my python-mode.el?

Comment: You may put it in your [init file](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html).

Comment: I'm getting an error: "Wrong type argument: listp, font-lock-keyword-face" with font-lock-mode enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 3):

With the current `python.el` mode as dstributed with Emacs 24.3 you can redefine the `python-fill-string` as follows (in this example, I also set the `fill-column` to 85 and change the `python-fill-docstring-style`):

```
;; Python customizations
(defun my-python-fill-string (&optional justify)
  (let ((old-fill-column fill-column))
    (setq fill-column 72)
    (python-fill-string justify)
    (setq fill-column old-fill-column)
  ))

(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda () (interactive)
            (setq python-fill-docstring-style 'pep-257-nn)
            (set-fill-column 85)
            (setq python-fill-string-function my-python-fill-string)
            ))
```